# Table conversion like rows

Tags: mysql, rows

I am creating report which is like

```
   fees     name   amount
  college  deepak   1000
  school   deepak   2000
```

I need the table as like below

```
 name       College       School   
 deepak      1000          2000
```

This is example, i will get multiple number of fees and names

Comment: Did u tried anything??

Comment: Just to give the man a break, it's not what I'd consider basic mysql usage. At least he knew he didn't knew how to perform that kind of aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the fees types beforehand, then the problem is trivial

```
select name, 
       sum(if(fees='college',amount,0)) as college
       sum(if(fees='school',amount,0)) as school
from userfees
group by name
```

if you don't know what fees might come up in the query, then it becomes much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT name, 
MAX(IF(fees='college',amount,0)) AS 'College',
MAX(IF(fees='school',amount,0)) AS 'School'
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY name;
```

**[FIND SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06194/4)**